# Override UITextView's UIScrollView Method touchEnded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uikit

I've a UITextView (from the InterfaceBuilder) in my View. This contains a UIScrollView.

Now I have to detect touch Events inside the UITextView beacause I must close my own submenus.

The Apple UITextView is in a UIScrollView, and to detect a touch in a UIScrollView I've to ovveride the UITouch Funktion of UITextView's UIScrollView.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView. Is this what you mean when you say "contains a UIScrollView?"

There are a couple of approaches you could take here. If the touch you are concerned with is the first touch in the text view, and is therefore beginning editing, you can become its delegate and implement this method:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

If you need to be aware of any tap that occurs inside the text view, not just initial editing taps, you can use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to listen for taps. Something like this:

```
// in the method where you configure your view
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textViewTapped:)] autorelease];
// assuming textView is pointing to your UITextView
[textView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And then implement the action method elsewhere in your class:

```
- (void)textViewTapped:(id)sender {
  // dismiss your menu or whatever
}
```

Note that I haven't actually tested this scenario, but it should work. Gesture recognizers are awesome.

Comment: This wasn't working, because there is a UIScrollView over the UITextView from the IB. So I had to ovveride the touchesBegan method of the UIWindow and send it to my selector.